# Mumford Red Book proof of surjective morphism of schemes is stable under base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am reading the following proof in the Red Book of Varieties and Schemes by Mumford saying that a surjective morphism of schemes is stable under base change and I came across some things that I didn't understand.

*"The maps $r^*$ and $s^*$ define inclusions of fields"*

The morphisms of schemes $r$ induces a map on stalks $\mathscr{O}_{S,r(x)}\to \mathscr{O}_{X,x}$, which is a local homomorphism, so we get a map $k(r(x))\to k(x)$. Why should this be an inclusion ? This might be obvious, but my intuition about this $k(x)$ is still very vague.

Edit: This is clear now, morphisms of fields are always injective.

*"defining $\alpha^*$ and $\beta^*$ to be the compositions"*

Here, he is defining what the map on stalks should be. Does this then immediately define the morphism of sheaves?

Any insight would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Any homomorphism of fields is an inclusion.

Comment: That is because kernels are ideals. As $1$ gets mapped to $1$ the kernel cannot be everything, thus is the zero ideal.

Comment: Thank you, of course. Do you also know the answer to my second question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question has already been handled by Daniel Hast and Severin Schraven in the comments: all morphisms of fields are injective because the kernel must be a proper ideal.

To answer your second question, the map $\mathcal{O}_X\to\alpha_*\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} \Omega}$ is specified by a compatible collection of maps $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to (\alpha_*\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} \Omega})(U)$ for $U\subset X$ open. But $(\alpha_*\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} \Omega})(U)$ is equal to $0$ when $x\notin U$ and $\Omega$ when $x\in U$, so we can define $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to (\alpha_*\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} \Omega})(U)$ as the zero map when $x\notin U$ and the map $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\to k(x) \to \Omega$ when $x\in U$. These maps are compatible because the map $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ factors as $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to\mathcal{O}_X(V)\to\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ for $x\in V\subset U$. So this really is enough to define the morphism you want.